# Buttons only trigger right/left movement once, not continually

Tags: unity, c#, movement, character-controller

I have a Unity mobile project where I am trying to use right/left movement using two UI buttons situated accordingly.  The issue is that it only moves the player to the right/to the left one time, not continually when the player is holding the button down.

I'd like the player to be able to hold down a certain button and have the character move constantly in that direction until the button is released.  I've tried making the void into a Coroutine, but nothing working works.

Here is my code.  (`rightCallable` and `leftCallable` are attached to the buttons).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class playerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public float speed = 1000f;
    public GameObject left;

    //this is so the player may also use the A and D keys if they want, and it works fine.
    public void Update()
    {
        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }

    //Below is what isn't working
    public void rightCallable ()
    {
        StartCoroutine("moveRight");
    }
    
    public void leftCallable ()
    {
        StartCoroutine("moveLeft");    
    }
    
    IEnumerator moveRight()
    {
        var movement = 1f;
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        yield return null;
    }
    IEnumerator moveLeft ()
    {
        var movement = -1f;
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
        yield return null;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public float speed = 1000f;
    public GameObject left;

    bool _isLeftHeld;
    bool _isRightHeld;

    public void Update()
    {
        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        // Ignore cases where neither/both left and right are held at once.
        if (_isRightHeld ^ _isLeftHeld) {
            // Override the movement input from the keyboard/joypad.
            if (_isRightHeld) movement = 1f;
            else movement = -1f;
        }

        // Act on the movement input in just one place, following the DRY principle.
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }         

    public void HoldRight(bool held)
    {
        _isRightHeld = held;
    }

    public void HoldLeft(bool held)
    {
        _isLeftHeld = held;
    }
}
```

Then add an `EventTrigger` component to each on-screen button.

Add two event types to this component: Pointer Down (to detect a press), and Pointer Up (to detect a release). Optionally, you can also detect Pointer Exit and treat that like a release.

When pressed, call your `HoldRight` or `HoldLeft` function respectively, and tick the checkbox to send the argument `true` ("The button is held").

When released, call your `HoldRight` or `HoldLeft` function respectively, and leave the checkbox unticked to send the argument `false` ("The button is *not* held").

It'll look something a bit like this:

[image: Inspector setup]